# Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'menuChoice' is being used without being initialized

Tags: c++, runtime

time error and i cant figure it out everything looks fine.  Here is my main:

```
#include "DoublyLinkedList.h"
#include "Stats.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

DoublyLinkedList<int>* statsList = new DoublyLinkedList<int>;

int main()
{
    Stats stats;
    bool exit = false;
    int menuChoice;
    while (!exit)
    {

        switch (menuChoice)
        {
        case 1:
        cout << "Insert";
        {

        stats.Details();

        }
            break;
        case 2:
        cout << "Delete";
        {
        }

            break;
        case 3:

            break;
        case 5:

            break;
        case 6:

            break;
        case 7:
            exit = true;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Before seeking to understand the whole error message, make sure you understand all the constituent words. For starters, *used* and *initialized*.

Comment: You need to set menuChoice to something before you use it.  Depending on your compiler it will do it for you but you might not like the value.  int menuChoice = -1; might be a better option when declaring the variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int menuChoice;
while (!exit)
{

    switch (menuChoice)
```

What do you expect `menuChoice` to be? 1? 0? 42?

It's undefined behavior reading from an uninitialized behavior, you should thank the run-time it's warning you, thus preventing a potential bug.

Answer (score 1):

You never set `menuChoice` to anything. You declare it and immediately use it.

Comment: Oh right i get it because it was used in a switch which expects a number by the user it has to be set to equal a number :) thanks i wasnt thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You use unitialized variable. This check in debug is good thing, but if you switch your project to release version - your code will work depends on "moon phase". So, always initialize variable by some value, before usage.